# SSIS Web service task, WSDL file not valid error

Tags: sql, web-services, ssis, wsdl

i am trying to run a SSIS package with a web service task from  a Sql server job, its failing with below error

Message

> Executed as user: UKDBT91DB05V\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   10:08:01  Error: 2013-04-25 10:08:02.68     Code: 0xC002F304
>   Source: DAD Web Service Task     Description: An error occurred with
>   the following error message:
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   The input Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file is not valid. 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil..ctor(Object
>   connection, String downloadedWSDL)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".
>   End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). 
>   Started:  10:08:01  Finished: 10:08:02  Elapsed:  1.014 seconds.  The
>   package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: And the question is?....

Comment: @Oscar hope the question is clear now :)

Comment: Try downloading the WSDL file manually and see if it's valid, using wsdl.exe tool in .Net SDK